# How to enable gzip for images in iis7?

Tags: iis-7, compression, gzip

I set dynamic compression and static compression on in iis7 manager. So html,css,js content is compressed ok and i see in headers Content-Encoding:gzip, but not with image formats: jpeg, gif and even bmp.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally speaking, you wouldn't want to. JPEG, GIF, and most (internet) image formats are already compressed. Compressing them a second time would add a lot of server overhead for very little size gain (and possibly a loss).

Comment: @x2: No, it's common sense  :)

Comment: -1 I've used fiddler to let me know how much would be saved - OK for my .pngs its neglible so not worth it, but for our jpgs its saying 50%

Comment: @BobTodd - It's really easy to try yourself (without fiddler), just `gzip -9 YourFavorite.jpg`. If you're achieving 50%, then I would guess your jpegs really small, and what you're really compressing is the jpeg header (which contains a lot of text). I would guess that nearly the same "compression ratio" could be achieved by stripping the jpeg metadata.

Comment: Incidentally, you can use [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) to strip out unnecessary stuff from pngs, which can yield a surprising size savings. There is likely a similar tool for jpeg.

Comment: in that case its better to use an imagemin :)